# HttpWebRequest Keep Connection and Reuse it

Tags: c#

So my basic idea is to create emails(yahoo for example) but for this purpose i need to open the connection, pass the captcha and then return it to the same connection so the captcha is still the same. I just need to know how to do that. I hope you got my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A CAPTCHA shouldn't require that the connection is kept alive. It should include some sort of token identifying the challenge in an opaque way - so long as you present that back to the server within the subsequent request, it should be fine.

(As it happens, `HttpWebRequest` *does* reuse connections, but that's an implementation detail you don't need to be aware of in most cases.)